# Changing Variables Values outside of component in Agular2

Tags: variables, angular, components

I'm trying to update my view variable by another component.

I want to update `{{userPictureThumbnail}}` in my `HeaderComponent` after user upload his new Profile Picture in my UserUploadPictureComponent.

My question is: how do I update `userPictureThumbnail` variable inside a callback in my `UserUploadPictureComponent()` function?

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [ProtectedDirective, HeaderComponent, FooterComponent],
    template: `
    <div class="page-container-bg-solid page-boxed page-md">
        <my-header *ngIf="isAuthenticated"></my-header>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <my-footer *ngIf="isAuthenticated"></my-footer>
    </div>
        `
})
```

I've tried `@Input()` and `@Inject()` without success.

Thank you!

Comment: where is your UserUploadPictureComponent ??? Are you using redux or any client state container?

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information to debug the problem.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is change a {{Variable}} value printed in a template (Header.html - this  {{Variable}} was defined before in Header.component.ts) in a callback outside of Header.component.ts. Is it possible?

Comment: i want to know same thing, but you have to write here both components or no one will respond.